# Reduce code using math operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code running under Ruby on Rails, it is working but I know that we can reduce it using math operators, it that right?

Here is the code that is actually running:

```
def pms_guest_purchase
if @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&
    #Plan MP 1 dia 2 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 1))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(62)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 4 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 2))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(64)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 6 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 3))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(104)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]      
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 8 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 4))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(105)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 10 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 5))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(106)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 12 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 6))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(107)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 14 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 7))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(108)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 14 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 8))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(109)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 14 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 9))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(110)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&    
    #Plan MP 1 dia 14 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i == 10))
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(111)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
```

end

I was trying this but looks like I’m doing wrong

```
if @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Rose Splash Portal" &&
    #Plan MP 1 dia 20 usuarios
    (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' &&  ((@guest.custom6) + (@guest.custom7)) == '2')
    @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(64)
    @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
```

`elsif @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Guest Splash Policy" &&
        #Plan MP 1 dia 20 usuarios
        (@guest.custom0 == 'MP' && ((@guest.custom6) + (@guest.custom7)) == '3')
        @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(104)
        @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]`

Here is the full fiel, if that helps.
[Full Code.](https://mega.nz/#!sNAH1C5K!p0Ms2ZLh8mb7AduK9-3poopOL8PL_TXIfxoK1mBwUuI)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was told that is kind similar, if I'm wrong I can changed It no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have to say that naming your fields 'custom6/7/8' is pretty terrible naming convention which will eventually lead to mass confusion and possibly the apocalypse.

If you want to make the number of connections a function of the number of people in the room (i.e. 2 people = 4 connections, 3 people = 6 connections, etc.) your code could be condensed down a lot to something like this

```
if @effective_portal && @effective_portal.name == "Guest Splash Policy" && 
 @guest.custom8 == 'MP PLATINO'
  @usage_plan = (@guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i * 2)
  @usage_plans = [ @usage_plan ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
This code is for an hotel, in the custom field (named custom1.. up to custom9) we put information there to provide internet connection plan according the information in those fields, here is what we store in those fields:
For Custom0, ALL = all-inclusive plan, this provide unlimited internet connection plan. MP = Meal Plan, limited internet access according the people in the room (we store that information in the custom6 and 7)
Custom6, here the front desk guys type the amount of adults in the room, and Custom7 is for children.

Comment: So basically what we do is apply an internet plan based on the type of guest (ALL or MP), in the case of MP guest, we provide 2 internet connections for user, that’s why we need to know the total of persons in the customs 6 & 7 when the Custom == MP. This make sense? 
That’s why I’m trying to reduce the code, because I did the same code for the all the results for the sum from custom6 & custom7, in the example I only used the result “10”

Comment: No sorry that doesn't make much sense. If you're always giving them two internet connections if they're MP regardless of how many people are in the room why do you need to test for it at all?

Comment: Let me try to explan It. Guest MP will get 2 devices per person, so, based on the people in the room we are going to provide a plan, for example: the room 1001 is under MP plan, there are 2 persons registered in the room, this means that I will provide a plan that allows 4 devices connected at the same time. Other example: Room 1002 is under MP plan, there are 3 persons (2 adults, 1 child) the system need to apply a plan that allows 6 devices connected at the same time. So I need to know how many people are in the room to apply the proper plan, that's why I need tu sum Custom6 & 7.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation in not so good. :) The values of Custom 6 & 7 are dinamic depending of the amount of people registered, I will put the complete code that I use for this, may be this will help.

Comment: So what you want isn't to test for the number of people who are in a room, it's too make the number of connections a function of the number of people in that room. Basically if they're an MP room you want to go to that condition regardless of the number of people in there, but then you need the max number of connections to be the number of people in the room * 2. I edited my code above to be something in that direction, though I'm not sure what you're doing with the `UsagePlan` stuff.

Comment: I tried with the code that you provided, worked with a little modification from mine, i just changed the * 2 by == 2 and the next numbers, I would like to keep it as you have it, but the plan ID is different depending the amount of guest inside the rooms.

Comment: "i just changed the * 2 by == 2" what does that mean? You changed that by adding an equality test? And how do the `UsagePlan` ids correspond with the number of people in the room (i.e. what would be the plan ids of rooms with 2, 3 and 4 people)?

Comment: The UsagePlan "usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(64)" is to asing the proper plan depending the amount of guest in the room, for example, the plan with the ID64 will provide 1 day of internet to 4 devices, so, depending of the result from guest.custom6.to_i + guest.custom7.to_i We will asing the match plan ID, I put the code as I have it now in the main Post (sorry i tried to added here but the Ctrl + k didn't work.

Comment: So your plan id has zero algebraic correspondence to the number of people in the room

Answer (score 0):

Start with a fake class, just for the purpose of illustration:

```
  class Guest

    attr_accessor :custom0, :custom6, :custom7, :custom8

    def initialize(args)
      args.each do |k,v|
        self.send("#{k}=",v)
      end
    end

  end
```

Create an array of `plan_id`s mapped to `number_of_guests` and `type_of_guest`:

```
  PLAN_POLICIES = [
    {number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 64},
    {number_of_guests: 10, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 53},
    {number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 63},
    {number_of_guests: 9, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 52},
    {number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 62},
    {number_of_guests: 8, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 51},
    {number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP PLATINO", plan_id: 61},
    {number_of_guests: 7, type_of_guest: "MP", plan_id: 50},
  ]
```

That's just some of them. You get the idea.

Create a few utility methods:

```
  def plan_id
    return PLAN_POLICIES.find do |pp|
      pp[:number_of_guests] == number_of_guests && pp[:type_of_guest] == type_of_guest
    end[:plan_id]    
  end

  def number_of_guests
    @guest.custom6.to_i + @guest.custom7.to_i
  end

  def type_of_guest
    return "MP" if @guest.custom0 == "MP"
    return "MP PLATINO" if @guest.custom8 == "MP PLATINO"
  end
```

Run it in console:

```
  2.3.1 :039 >  @guest = Guest.new(custom6: '1', custom7: '9', custom8: 'MP PLATINO')
  2.3.1 :040 >  plan_id
   => 64 
  2.3.1 :041 >  @guest = Guest.new(custom6: '2', custom7: '6', custom8: 'MP PLATINO')
  2.3.1 :042 >  plan_id
   => 62 
  2.3.1 :043 >  @guest = Guest.new(custom0: "MP", custom6: '10', custom7: '')
  2.3.1 :044 >  plan_id
   => 53 
  2.3.1 :045 >  @guest = Guest.new(custom0: "MP", custom6: '2', custom7: '5')
  2.3.1 :046 >  plan_id
   => 50
```

Use it something like:

```
  @usage_plan = UsagePlan.find_by_id(plan_id)
```

Turn ~200 lines of code into ~40 lines of code. Happiness!

By the way, you *really* shouldn't be coding `ids` in by hand. That'll bite you eventually.

Comment: Thanks! @jvillian, I tried what you suggested, but got some errors: class definition in method body, and, dynamic constant assignment
  PLAN_POLICIES = [,  why could be the reason?, thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you have your code in the wrong places. If you post what you have as a separate question, I'll take a look. If you decide to post, leave a message here so I get a notification.